# How to remove extra NavigationBar in splash screen Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, uinavigationbar, splash-screen

I'm building a Xamarin CrossPlatform App!

I added a splash screen in my app which is working fine, but the problem is it gives me an extra navigation bar on top which I don't want to be in my app `MainPage`

Screenshot:

[image]

Here is my code of splash screen :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Last_MSPL.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class SplashPage : ContentPage
    {
        Image splashImage;


        public SplashPage()
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

            var sub = new AbsoluteLayout();
            splashImage = new Image
            {
                Source = "truck.png",
                WidthRequest = 300,
                HeightRequest = 300
            };
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(splashImage,
               AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(splashImage,
             new Rectangle(0.5, 0.5, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));

            sub.Children.Add(splashImage);

            this.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#FFF");
            this.Content = sub;
        }


        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            await splashImage.ScaleTo(1, 500); //Time-consuming processes such as initialization
            await splashImage.ScaleTo(0.9,1800, Easing.CubicInOut);
            //await splashImage.ScaleTo(0, 1600, Easing.Linear);
            Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());    //After loading  MainPage it gets Navigated to our new Page
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If Main page is master detail then just replace Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage(); no need of Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

Comment: May be because of that its giving you extra navigation bar on top.

Comment: @MShah Thanks Buddy it works !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Main page is master detail then just replace 
`Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();` no need of `Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());`

May be because of that its giving you extra navigation bar on top.